# Plot histogram for each group dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Let's cosnider very easy dataframe containing four groups:

```
cat <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3)
var <- c(10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 10, 50, 2, 30)

df <- data.frame(cat, var)
```

What I would like to do is that using `dplyr` plot distribution of values between those four categories

I have the feeling that it can be eaisly done with `group_by`, but I'm not sure how it can be done. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Try `ggplot(df, aes(var, group = cat)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ cat)`

Comment: what if I would like a normalized histogram? Is there an opportunity to have it?

Comment: Perhaps `ggplot(df, aes(var, group = cat)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~ cat)`